# SHA256 implementation for J2ME

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sha256

Please provide the implementation class for SHA256 algoritham in J2ME.I want this encoding to be done in blackberry apps.

Answer (score -2):

Look here http://www.docjar.com/html/api/gnu/java/security/hash/Sha256.java.html

More about SHA-2 (SHA-256/512) [are here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)

Comment: It is the implementation in j2se.But i need the implementation in J2ME for use in Blackberry apps.